# Flask-SQLAlchemy backref function and backref parameter

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In Flask-SQLAlchemy, the backref parameter in relationship method allows you to declare a new property under a specified class as seen in the example in their [docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#one-to-many-relationships):

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

But then there is also a `backref` function:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address',
                                backref=db.backref('person', lazy='joined'), 
                                lazy='dynamic')
```

In this case, what's the role of the `backref` function passed to the `backref` parameter, especially with the multiple `lazy` definitions? How is it different from `backref='person'`?

Comment: Using the backref object you can change the behaviour/configuration of the back reference relationship. In your case `Address.person` has joined loading configured. When you pass just a string, you get the defaults.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Doesn't `lazy='dynamic'` also change the loading configuration? I think this is what is confusing me

Comment: Yes. It changes the configuration of the relationship the keyword argument is passed to. In your case `User.addresses`.

Comment: Using `backref` just automates the creation of a relationship property at the other end. `backref='person'` is somewhat akin to having `person = db.relationship('Person')` explicitly in the Address class (+ back population). Using the `backref()` object you can pass arguments to that relationship.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the documentation for Flask models](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/):

`backref` is a simple way to also declare a new property on the Address class. You can then also use `my_address.person` to get to the person at that address. `lazy` defines when SQLAlchemy will load the data from the database:

`select` (which is the default) means that SQLAlchemy will load the data as necessary in one go using a standard select statement.

`joined` tells SQLAlchemy to load the relationship in the same query as the parent using a JOIN statement.

`subquery` works like 'joined' but instead, SQLAlchemy will use a subquery.

`dynamic` is special and useful if you have many items. Instead of loading the items SQLAlchemy will return another query object which you can further refine before loading the items. This is usually what you want if you expect more than a handful of items for this relationship.

Comment: Yes I understand this part. My question is what is the role of the backref function passed to the backref parameter. How is it different from `db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy='dynamic')`

Comment: It's not possible to cascade any further inside a function call. I guess they created this function to encapsulate the scoping issue and for redundancy.

Comment: Which scoping issue? And why create a redundant function whose call you can pass to a parameter with the same name on a function that offers its exact functionality?

Answer (score 1):

the second lazy define the lazy status for backref. For example:

```py
addresses = db.relationship('Address',
         backref=db.backref('person', lazy='joined'), lazy='dynamic')
```

lazy='joined' define the lazy status for 'person'
lazy='dynamic' define the lazy status for addresses